# text-align: center is on the right

Tags: html

text-align:center; not working. the text "hello" starts on the right side of the page and not the center. i need the text to be placed right exactly on the middle of the page. pls help and thanks.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffd200;
}

h1 {
  font-size;
  10em;
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'arial';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Comment: Why are you setting "position: absolute"?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to vertically align in center also use flex

use flex properties
//

```
  h1 {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    just use text-align;
    }
```

for horizontal align

```
 body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background: #ffd200;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 10em;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'arial';
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <h1>hello</h1>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: That solves the horizontal alignment but it breaks the vertical alignment.

Comment: check my edit post

Comment: Your edit broke the live demo feature. Try putting it back. (And your new CSS doesn't work because there is no selector and has some random non-CSS text in the middle of it

Answer (score -1):

Try this (updated): http://jsfiddle.net/ody9tfrn/6/

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffd200;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
}
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
```

Comment: I turned your code into a live demo, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure about that, i tried and it worked, look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ody9tfrn/3/

Comment: The tiny font size there conceals the problem. Make the font size larger or use the demo here on Stackoverflow where it already is a decent size. The top left corner of the text is in the middle of the page when the middle of the text should be in the middle of the page.

Comment: I see, sorry about that. You can try flexbox. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ody9tfrn/6/